# Why sysfs and procfs aren't displayed by df on Linux?

Tags: linux, procfs, sysfs

When I type `df -Th` I only get this :

```
$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs  987M  2.1M  984M   1% /run
/dev/sda3      ext4    59G   34G   23G  60% /
tmpfs          tmpfs  4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs  5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1      vfat   197M   29M  169M  15% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs  987M  4.7M  982M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Why `sysfs` and `procfs` aren't displayed ? I thought `df` had to display all the file systems on my computer.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This answer assumes you are using [df from the GNU coreutils](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/5450c7f8d33f7a9ee10a2700cad9ccc6cec3626e/src/df.c))*

This is the intended behavior, as `df` will not show all mounted filesystems unless explicitely asked to with `-a` (see [here for the discard rules](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/5450c7f8d33f7a9ee10a2700cad9ccc6cec3626e/src/df.c#L746)). In the case of `sysfs` and `procfs`, they are discarded since they are marked as dummy filesystems.

The mount list is obtained from GNU Gnulib and it has rules about which filesystems it marks as dummy: see [here](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/mountlist.c#L164).